# Is there a way to run git rebase --abort without switching branches?

Tags: git

Suppose I've been working on a local branch for a week. Now I'm ready to upload it for code review, but first I'd like to update my master branch and then rebase my local branch on it.

So, after updating my master branch, I run:

```
git rebase master mybranch
```

Uh-oh! I'm getting tons and tons of merge conflicts. Instead of rebasing I want to use merging, or maybe rebase --onto, or something else like that.

So I run:

```
git rebase --abort
```

Now here's the problem - after aborting, it checks out mybranch.

I don't want it to do that. Is there any way to run "git rebase --abort" but leave "master" checked out?

Possible reasons why not:

- The repository has a lot of files and it's slow to check them all out.
- I just compiled "master" from source and it takes a while to compile. Checking out last week's code means recompiling from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't check out mybranch after the abort; checking out mybranch is the first thing it does. From `git-rebase(1)`:

```
git rebase [-i | --interactive] [options] [--exec <cmd>] [--onto <newbase>]
    [<upstream> [<branch>]]

...

If <branch> is specified, git rebase will perform an automatic git
checkout <branch> before doing anything else. Otherwise it remains on
the current branch.
```

Here, `mybranch` is `<branch>`, so whether you abort or continue the rebase, it has already checked out `mybranch` at the very start.

Comment: That's what it says, but that's not what it does in practice.

Comment: I just tried this by checking out branch `foo`, running `git rebase foo master`, knowing it would fail on conflicts, and now `git branch` tells me I am on master. No abort or continue has been run yet, it has already checked out the master branch. (Git 2.6.2 if it matters.)